# You're asking a dumb question!!1!

Tags: discussion, comments

*New contributor*  or not, when a question is asked, that may for one or more reasons be eligible for putting on hold, the first few comments I've been seeing lately can be read as *you're asking a dumb question.*

I implore the community – instead of pointing out the obvious *(which isn't obvious to many)* – to offer edit suggestions and only vote-to-close when it is absolutely a no-brainer.

This is in-line with the [commenting guidelines](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), which are increasingly being misused IMO.

> When should I comment?
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

(I didn't leave out any part of that section.)

Imagine a random person leaving a Post-it on your desk that reads, "You're doing a bad job," and offering no hint at what you're doing wrong. This is the analogy to the comments that don't offer a way to improve the post.

I've tagged it [discussion] (this is not a Q&A), so if you want to have your say by posting an *answer* below, please do.

Comment: You're doing a *great* job! Anyway not worth an answer, but I cant stress enough how *everyone* needs to remember what comments are for. Exactly as quoted here.

Comment: Also, PLEASE flag unkind comments. We'll get them removed.

Comment: Is the mod-team in agreement that unhelpful comments = unkind? Also an upvote would be nice @Jamiec, they're free here and would help getting it to the main page; it's like an abandoned warehouse here ;-)

Comment: There you go (+1). Can you provide examples? I want to make sure that we haven't missed those comments.

Comment: I prefer not to, sorry @Farhan. I don't want to single anyone out by accident. The problem is unhelpful ≠ unkind as far as I understand the flag system. Can I have my comedic title back? I've edited it back if it's okay :)

Comment: However, regarding "unhelpful comments = unkind", I don't think we (nor mods) can put a blanket statement like that. General "unhelpful" comments are just "no longer needed", until it's offensive that makes them "unkind" or even "rude"...

Comment: This can be relevant to Stack Exchange in general -- definitely not a problem limited just to aviation.SE.

Comment: Unhelpful but humourous comments are usually welcome here.

Comment: @vasin1987 - Yes. Funny comments are also not unconstructive.

Comment: my sidebar lists a related post: [Can we please leave contructive comments for our new users, instead of simply downvoting?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3338/6919); linking it here in case the related post algorithm changes down the line.

Comment: I too have noticed the SE system is vulnerable to basement dwellers that kill boars until they have massive experience points then go on a pathetic pseudo-superiority power trip deleting and down voting everything that contradicts their modest education. Rather than simply making a reasonable comment about what they don't like and waiting for clarification. (Boars reference Southpark WoW guy.)

Answer (score 9):

This is a familiar issue across SE as has been [noted](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3764/youre-asking-a-dumb-question1?cb=1#comment4518_3764).

A few years ago I [lamented much the same thing](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6798/106801) over in EL&U meta, suggesting a repository of helpful comments to help guide folks in addressing issues with the question, while using more welcoming and inclusive language.

Comment: Computer Science SE has such a [repository](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/627/reference-templates-for-common-comments/). It's pretty useful.